# HTTPS Get gives connection refused error while connecting to Bing API using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, http-get, bing-api

I was able to connect to the Bing API end point using Chrome extension - Postman.
I am new to NodeJS and AWS Lambda.  Seeing the below error while connecting from an AWS Lambda function with nodejs 6.9.0

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)

Code:

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
var headers = {
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '******************',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};
var options = {
url: 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?                
&q=hello',
method: 'GET',
headers: headers,
};
const https = require("https");
https.get(options);
};
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may require and use the package [node-bing-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bing-api) to search with Bing Api.

```
var Bing = require('node-bing-api')({ accKey: "your-account-key" });

Bing.web("hello", function(error, res, body){
   console.log(body);
 });
```